# Spring Form:Select selected value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I know this has been asked before but the solutions provided doesn't seem to work on my end.

I'm currently developing a web application and I'm currently working on the user profile page. What I'm doing is that when the user visits his/her  profile, he/she will be able to manage his/her profile.

I have a spring form:select box which populates a List of RolesObject and a List of GroupsObject passed from the controller. The object consists of an id and name fields. What I want is when the form:select loads, it will select the present role id and group id of the user from the list.

controller

```
public ModelAndView viewProfile(parameters) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("viewProfile");
...
    List<RolesObject> roles = rolesService.getRolesList();
    List<GroupsObject> groups = groupsService.getGroupsList();
    Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();

    map.put("roles", roles);
    map.put("groups", groups);
    mav.addObject("map", map);

return mav;
```

view

```
<form:select path="role_id" id="role_id" cssClass="form-control" cssStyle="width: 100%;" value="${current.getRole_id()}" required="required">
<c:forEach var="role" items="${map.roles}">
<form:option value="${role.getId()}" label="${role.getName()}" />
</c:forEach>
</form:select>

<form:select path="group_id" id="group_id" cssClass="form-control" cssStyle="width: 100%;" value="${current.getGroup_id()}" required="required">
<c:forEach var="group" items="${map.groups}">
<form:option value="${group.getId()}" label="${group.getName()}" />
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

My problem is the list populates but it does not select a default value.

Let's say my role values are 
value=1, label=role_1
value=2, label=role_2

and the user's current role is role_2 which has an id of 2, when the select form loads, it does not automatically load role_2 but instead still shows role_1 as the selected value

Answer (score 0):

For preselection of the option you need to set the role_id and group_id in the controller and set it as the modelattribute of the form object on page.